# Can't connect symfony 4 container with mysql Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony

I'm trying to make a docker configuration with four containers : 
- a React container 
- a Symfony 4 container 
- a Mysql container
- and an Nginx container

I've made a docker-compose, dockerfiles and everything run well except when i tried to access to my database from my PHP container.

By making researches, i guess the problem comes from my docker-compose or my .env file.
I tried many things, mainly by changing the URL connection in the .env file.
Here is my URL : 
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@**172.21.0.4**:3306/Lucci

(It's currently the container's IP. I've tried in changing it with "mysql" (container's name), "127.0.0.1", "localhost"

so, here is my docker-compose :

```
version:  '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - back-network
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: 1000:1000
    networks:
      - back-network
  react:
    build:
      context : ./LucciFront
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - back-network
networks:
  front-network:
    driver: bridge
  back-network:
    driver: bridge
```

my .env file :

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=010556a2891ecc0273593c31e17b9399
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/     en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@172.21.0.4:3306/Lucci
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"

MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

###> doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ###
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
MONGODB_DB=symfony
###< doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ###

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

and my dockerfile of the php's container :

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN chmod -R 777 ./

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
zlib1g-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && php composer-setup.php --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY apps/LucciBack /usr/src/app

RUN PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/apps/vendor/bin:bin
RUN composer install
RUN php bin/console doctrine:database:create
RUN php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

When i run docker-compose build, i've got :

```
Step 14/15 : RUN php bin/console doctrine:database:create
 ---> Running in 2c77cac8c604
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed ou
  t


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

I've got no error when i run "docker-compose up -d", but i guess it just passes the database creation.

Edit : 
Here are the last message for each container on "docker-compose up":

```
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.294975Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure co                                                                                                          nfiguration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to                                                                                                           all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.309669Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/my                                                                                                          sqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.soc                                                                                                          k'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.423127Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin rea                                                                                                          dy for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port:                                                                                                           33060

php_1    | [28-Oct-2019 12:31:43] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.294975Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure co                                                                                                          nfiguration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to                                                                                                           all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.309669Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/my                                                                                                          sqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.soc                                                                                                          k'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_1  | 2019-10-28T12:31:44.423127Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin rea                                                                                                          dy for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port:                                                                                                           33060

react_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2019:14:10:50 +0000] "GET /static/media/brand-icons.e8c322de.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 54488 "http://localhost/static/css/2.727d7221.chunk.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.107" "-"
react_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2019:14:10:50 +0000] "GET /static/media/icons.0ab54153.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 40148 "http://localhost/static/css/2.727d7221.chunk.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.107" "-"
react_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2019:14:10:51 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3870 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.107" "-"
```

After running the command, i can access to my react app, but got nothing from the database

Edit 2:

Here is the error message when i replace the container's IP address by the name of the container (here "mysql").

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr
  esses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o
  r service not known


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o
  r service not known


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or s
  ervice not known


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

and here is my URL connection :
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/Lucci

Comment: Couple of things. First, why do you have multiple networks if you only use one? Docker-compose automatically creates a network for all services it runs, so a multi-network setup is only useful if you are going to use multiple components. Second,  you only need to refer to the mysql container by name. Localhost would never work, nor would 127.0.0.1. What happens when you do docker-compose up instead of build? My bets are it's dying before compose actually has a chance to setup the mysql container (Which takes time after starting to prep)

Comment: I edited my message to put the log from docker-compose up. I used multiple networks to try the functionality, but originally, i just wanted one. 
But apparently, i don't need this functionality, i will remove it from my docker-compose